# Как узнать объем выделенной памяти веб-приложению?

Tags: javascript, память

Можно ли узнать объем памяти, которую использует веб приложение, средствами js во время работы?

Если нет, то какие инструменты для этого можно использовать? Можно ли это увидеть через инструменты разработчика в браузере?

Comment: в инструментах разработчика в последнее время стали добавлять различный профилировщики, а частности в хроме

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Developer Tools в Хроме есть вкладка Profiles. Там есть два варианта - можно снять снэпшот текущего потребления памяти или запустить запись потребления и потом посмотреть, как оно изменялось на временной шкале. Более подробную информацию можете прочитать в [документации](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/heap-snapshots).